# How to list all the leap year from 1800 in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have this code below which takes one parameter and prints all the list of leap year in reverse order. how can I make it take 1800 as default input and just run command (leap) to list all the leap years from 1800-2018?

CODE:

```
(defun leap (q)

    (if (< q 1800)
        (RETURN-FROM leap nil)
    )

    (leap (- q 1))

    (if (leapyear q)
        (push q mylist)
    )
    mylist
)


(reverse(leap 2018))
```

Comment: If `q` should default to `1800`, how would `(leap)` produce the leap years between 1800 and 2018? Where does `2018` come from?

Answer (score 2):

I can't completely understand what you are trying to do, but:

```
(defun leapyearp (y)
  ;; is Y a leap year, as best we can tell?
  (= (nth-value 3 (decode-universal-time
                   (+ (encode-universal-time 0 0 0 28 2 y)
                      (* 60 60 24))))
     29))

(defun leapyears (&key (start 1800) (end (nth-value 5 (get-decoded-time))))
  ;; all the leap years in a range
  (loop for y from start to end
        if (leapyearp y) collect y))
```